# Exhausted after ice dipping

Tags: swimming, cold

I am a reasonably experienced swimmer and I was swimming in the nearby lake almost every day through the summer and autumn. I live in northern Europe, and I was still swimming occasionally in October when the water was around 15 degrees Celsius, and had no problem with it.

Yesterday the weather was nice and sunny, so I thought I would give it a try and dip in the water, which was around 1-2 degrees Celsius (the nearby puddles were frozen). I read a lot about the benefits of cold water, and was curious to try. I am generally fit and healthy and many people do ice dipping around this time of the year, so I thought why not.

I was only able to stay in about a minute as it was very cold, but I felt very good afterwards so I went in for another minute. Then I covered myself if a thermo blanket, drank some hot tea, walked home, and took a warm shower. However, I got very exhausted and slept for the rest of the day, and also through the night (around 12 hours, which is unusual).

Cold water therapy is [reported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_swimming#Health_benefits) to have an energising effect and a positive impact on fitness:

> When compared to a control group on the profile of mood states rating scale, winter swimmers experience less stress and fatigue and more vigor. They report to have a better memory function, better mood and feel more energetic, active and brisk.

I can confirm the positive impact on mood. However, I was definitely experiencing *more* fatigue and was feeling *less* energetic afterwards.

Is it normal to feel exhausted after a short dip in extremely cold water?

Answer (score 6):

For someone cold-challenged, or actually in hypothermia, your body is going to use a ton of energy to rewarm you and you'd likely feel the effect of [blood shunting](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/01/16/nyregion/what-happens-to-people-when-temperature-plunges.html).

It's the difference between "a dip" versus your study ([linked in Wikipedia](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3402/ijch.v63i2.17700)) which talked about "swimming", the latter of which generates enough heat in a trained athlete to stave off hypothermia.

The linked NY Times piece above backs that suspicion up:

> If the muscles cannot generate enough heat and the fat insulation is
> insufficient to keep what heat there is from draining away, the body's
> reaction is to try to preserve the heat it generates. Most body heat
> is lost through the skin, whose large surface area drains heat away
> from the blood into the cold air. To prevent this heat loss, the body
> shunts blood away from the skin, with the result that you feel cold.

[On the heat (hyperthermia) side, it can take about two weeks for your body to adjust by doing things like reducing salt sweated out, not as much vasoconstricting, etc](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/36341/7091). A [2007 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17929604) shows that cold acclimatization takes about the same amount of time:

> The results suggest that cold adaptation induced by winter swimming
> attenuates the catecholamine responses to cold water. Adrenaline
> responses are also affected by its level prior to the immersion.

A [2001 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11590880) states pretty clearly that regular exposure and training in cold water changes one's [hormonal responses (the catecholamine response noted above)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catecholamine), which is how shunting and other physiological changes occur:

> The results suggest that cold adaptation induced by winter swimming
> attenuates the catecholamine responses to cold water. Adrenaline
> responses are also affected by its level prior to the immersion.

In short, [the study you're referencing](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.3402/ijch.v63i2.17700) is for people who were cold-conditioned prior to the study ("regular winter swimming"), and unlike your experience, they were aerobically engaged.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I think the answer is incomplete though, as 2 minutes is nowhere near enough for hypothermia to occur, so what might be causing the exhaustion is still unclear for me.

Comment: Hypothermia can absolutely happen that fast, and shunting happens within seconds. Read up on climbers falling into crevaces. If they're not scooped out within minutes survivability drops rapidly.

Comment: Survival is a different question. Hypothermia means the core body temperature falls below 35 degrees Celsius which does not happen in 1-2 minutes. Shunting happens to prevent it actually.

Comment: https://useakayak.org/references/hypothermia_table.html loss of dexterity in 2 minutes, potentially unresponsive in 15

Comment: I am not concerned about loss of dexterity. The question I would like to understand is what mechanism might cause exhaustion hours after being immersed to ice cold water for a short time. Is it the hormonal response you mention?